# Android REST API made on PHP connect to app

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-volley

First hello everyone and thanks for your help, sorry for bad english and if this is a stupid question I'm not that good on programming.

So I'm doing an app for my graduation and I'm having this problem I made the connection to the API in the usual way making an config class with the URL of the API that I made in PHP, but I can't seem to connect to it, I don't know where the problem is and I made with StrRequest here the code:

```
  private void registerUser(final String name, final String email, final String password) {
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            pDialog.hide();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");

                    db.addUser(name, email, uid);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name + " was registered succefully, try to log in now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

But I heard that is meant to be made with the AsyncTaks but I have no idea of how to convert or how to use it or if I need to remake everything from scratch. Thanks for the help anyway and sorry if it looks stupid.

edit The error logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lucass.mywatchinglist_11, PID: 1510
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lucass.mywatchinglist_11.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:164)
at com.lucass.mywatchinglist_11.RegisterActivity.novoUsuario(RegisterActivity.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are using Volley, so you don't need an AsyncTask

Comment: You should provide the error log, or the response of the post request ;)

Comment: Well here it is: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lucass.mywatchinglist_11.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:164)

Comment: thanks a lot guys, the params are null so it tries to access a null parameter returning the erro I think I need to create a helper class, thanks again guys ^^